# Clustering any java application on weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, clusterize

I am new to clustering on Weblogic and read [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/core.1111/e10106/aa.htm#ASHIA4079). Now I want to know that is that possible to cluster any java application on Weblogic? in [that tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/core.1111/e10106/aa.htm#ASHIA4079) is discussed about Ejb-based applications. My application has no framework and is just simple JavaEE application and I want to cluster it on weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
This is simply replicate your app into multiple servers and a load balancer on top of these will distribute the requests among them. 
You have to only check your resource (server, database etc.) support it and there is no multithreading / concurrency issue with your code.